# Passing HTML variable into Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to pass variable in Jquery. variable contains path of a csv file.
like: `x = /data/files/12.csv`
now I want to pass this x variable in jquery and also access it in jquery code.

Can anybody help me in solving this?

Thanks

Comment: Too vague.  But you could always do `window.x = "/data/files/12.csv";` and then access the variable from anywhere.

Comment: Could you explain (a) where this value is and (b) what you want to do with it? Your question is a long way from being answerable...

Comment: `x` is some variable in your server side programming language? What do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I would set a hidden input to the value and reference that with javascript/jQuery.  For example:

HTML:

```
<input id="myFile" type=hidden value="/data/files/12.csv">
```

JQuery:

```
var myFile = $('#myFile').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a global variable (though global variables are generally not preferred):

```
window.csv = '/data/files/12.csv'
```

Or you can associate the data with a set of matched element using jQuery's `data` method:

```
$('#exampleElem').data('csv', '/data/files/12.csv');
```

Or you can pass the data through an event handler:

```
$('#exampleBtn').bind(
    'click', 
    { csv: '/data/files/12.csv' }, 
    function() { /* handle the click */ }
);
```

There are certainly other ways as well. Which method you pick is up to you and your situation.